# MSSQL to create temporary identity column when selecting from table

Tags: sql-server

I have a temporary table that I am selecting all the records from. Say it looks like this:

```
select * from #mytable
```

I need to add a temporary identity field to that selection. I've looked around and suggestions include using the IDENTITY(1,1) keyword in some fashion or just creating an auto-incrementing field like this:

```
row_Number() over (order by col1, col2) as myid
```

But that doesn't make the column an identity, it just creates a uniquely incremented field.

I know there should be a simple solution to this but I just can't find it.

Comment: IF its a temp table, just add the identity on the temp table creation.

Comment: How is the table created?  Why do you need to add an IDENTITY column?  You will get much better answers if your question is complete.

Comment: Identify which of your fields fulfill the function of a primary key, so you can create a unique identity column

Comment: The contents of the table are of no concern to me here, I want to be able to do this with several tables both temporary and not. I just want to know if it's possible to create a key identity field while doing a select. I don't want to add the identity to the creation of the initial table.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to know if it's possible to create a key identity field
>   while doing a select

Only by `SELECT INTO`:

```
SELECT IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS IdentityColumn
,* 
INTO #Temp 
FROM sys.databases
```

But not via a plain SELECT, since IDENTITY is nothing more than just a column property that involves proprietary sequence generator and **it works only on INSERT**

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT INTO

```
 SELECT
 IDENTITY (INT, 1, 1) AS NEW_ID, *
 INTO #tempTable
 FROM #mytable

 SELECT * FROM #tempTable
```